# Why is God unbeatable?

Tags: nature-of-god

Why is God unbeatable? There is no record in the Bible of God ever being beaten at anything, and Satan has been trying since the beginning of time. No human or animal could ever hope to compete with God. Is there a reason other than omnipotence that this is the case? I honestly feel that giving the omnipotence reason is just a cop-out, because even though God can do anything, that is still not a true reason. Why is God unbeatable?

Comment: This question isn't really about Christianity, it's about the Nature of God, but doesn't appeal to any particular Christian principles and could be answered with pure philosophy.  If you can scope your question to a given Christian denomination or sect that would be much better; you'll get more succinct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what we have said is even more clear if another priest like
> Melchizedek appears, one who has become a priest not on the basis
> of a regulation as to his ancestry but on the basis of **the power of an
> indestructible life**. (Hebrews 7:15-16)

God is the uncaused cause. Your question has no answer. God is indestructible, unchangeable, righteous and loving. That is what He is. There is no "why" that can be answered about the matter. God exists as He is, and that existence is by nature something that cannot be overcome. If God is perfect love, then any who oppose him are not love, hence must be vanquished that the objects of God's love may be saved from their evil.

One may object that it appears that God does lose and often. This tied up in God's timing and patience. God permits temporary setbacks as part of His plan, but promises that when that plan comes to its fruition, all adversaries will be defeated, including Satan, death, Hades and Leviathan. Because of this, God's unbeatable nature, like all His attributes, must be accepted on faith.